# Error while updating SDK build tools from 26.0.1 to 26.0.2 in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, build-tools

Error displayed while installing update:

```
lib/monitor-x86_64/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/DefaultProfile.profile/.data/.settings/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.prefs    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/DefaultProfile.profile/.data/.settings/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.contributors.1   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.namespaces.1 Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.manager/.fileTable.7 Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.manager/.fileTableLock   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.manager/.fileTable.8 Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.manager/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.mainData.1   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.table.1  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.contributions.1  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.orphans.1    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.extraData.1  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.update/last.config.stamp   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.update/history/1491325789000.xml   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.update/history/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.app/.manager/.fileTableLock    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.app/.manager/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.app/   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/159/1/.cp/icons/full/eview16/bkmrk_nav.gif    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/159/1/.cp/icons/full/eview16/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/159/1/.cp/icons/full/etool16/newprj_wiz.gif   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/159/1/.cp/icons/full/etool16/newfile_wiz.gif  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/159/1/.cp/icons/full/etool16/newfolder_wiz.gif    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/159/1/.cp/icons/full/etool16/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/159/1/.cp/icons/full/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/159/1/.cp/icons/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/159/1/.cp/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/159/1/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/159/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/151/1/.cp/libswt-gtk-4236.so  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/151/1/.cp/libswt-pi-gtk-4236.so   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/151/1/.cp/libswt-atk-gtk-4236.so  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/151/1/.cp/libswt-cairo-gtk-4236.so    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/151/1/.cp/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/151/1/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/151/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/155/1/.cp/icons/full/cview16/console_view.gif Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/155/1/.cp/icons/full/cview16/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/155/1/.cp/icons/full/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/155/1/.cp/icons/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/155/1/.cp/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/155/1/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/155/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1/1/.cp/libs/kxml2-2.3.0.jar  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1/1/.cp/libs/guava-19.0.jar   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1/1/.cp/libs/dvlib.jar    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1/1/.cp/libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1/1/.cp/libs/sdklib.jar   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1/1/.cp/libs/httpmime-4.1.jar Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1/1/.cp/libs/httpcore-4.2.5.jar   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1/1/.cp/libs/commons-compress-1.0.jar Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1/1/.cp/libs/common.jar   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1/1/.cp/libs/annotations.jar  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1/1/.cp/libs/layoutlib-api.jar    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1/1/.cp/libs/httpclient-4.2.6.jar Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1/1/.cp/libs/sdk-common.jar   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1/1/.cp/libs/commons-codec-1.6.jar    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1/1/.cp/libs/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1/1/.cp/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1/1/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/1/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/50/1/.cp/icons/full/dlcl16/new_con.gif    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/50/1/.cp/icons/full/dlcl16/copy_edit_co.gif   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/50/1/.cp/icons/full/dlcl16/rem_co.gif Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/50/1/.cp/icons/full/dlcl16/collapseall.gif    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/50/1/.cp/icons/full/dlcl16/   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/50/1/.cp/icons/full/eview16/debug_persp.gif   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/50/1/.cp/icons/full/eview16/breakpoint_view.gif   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/50/1/.cp/icons/full/eview16/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/50/1/.cp/icons/full/ovr16/transparent.gif Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/50/1/.cp/icons/full/ovr16/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/50/1/.cp/icons/full/elcl16/delete_config.gif  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/50/1/.cp/icons/full/elcl16/new_con.gif    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/50/1/.cp/icons/full/elcl16/filter_ps.gif  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/50/1/.cp/icons/full/elcl16/copy_edit_co.gif   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/50/1/.cp/icons/full/elcl16/collapseall.gif    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/50/1/.cp/icons/full/elcl16/   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/50/1/.cp/icons/full/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/50/1/.cp/icons/   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/50/1/.cp/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/50/1/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/50/   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/images/push.png   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/images/thread.png Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/images/add.png    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/images/debug-attach.png   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/images/delete.png Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/images/halt.png   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/images/heap.png   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/images/hprof.png  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/images/capture.png    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/images/tracing_start.png  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/images/pull.png   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/images/gc.png Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/images/   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/libs/ddmlib.jar   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/libs/jfreechart-1.0.9.jar Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/libs/ddmuilib.jar Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/libs/jfreechart-swt-1.0.9.jar Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/libs/uiautomatorviewer.jar    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/libs/jcommon-1.0.12.jar   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/libs/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/icons/thread.png  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/icons/ddms-16.png Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/icons/emulator-16.png Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/icons/uiautomator.png Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/icons/logcat.png  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/icons/heap.png    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/icons/networkstats.png    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/icons/device.png  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/icons/systrace.png    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/icons/android.png Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/icons/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/.cp/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/1/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/2/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/65/1/.cp/icons/full/obj16/layout_co.gif   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/65/1/.cp/icons/full/obj16/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/65/1/.cp/icons/full/etool16/fastview_restore.gif  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/65/1/.cp/icons/full/etool16/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/65/1/.cp/icons/full/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/65/1/.cp/icons/   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/65/1/.cp/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/65/1/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/65/   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/5/1/.cp/images/ddms-16.png    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/5/1/.cp/images/ddms-32.png    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/5/1/.cp/images/ddms-128.png   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/5/1/.cp/images/   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/5/1/.cp/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/5/1/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/5/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/40/1/.cp/os/linux/x86_64/libunixfile_1_0_0.so Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/40/1/.cp/os/linux/x86_64/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/40/1/.cp/os/linux/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/40/1/.cp/os/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/40/1/.cp/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/40/1/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/40/   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/138/1/.cp/org/eclipse/jface/wizard/images/stop.gif    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/138/1/.cp/org/eclipse/jface/wizard/images/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/138/1/.cp/org/eclipse/jface/wizard/   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/138/1/.cp/org/eclipse/jface/action/images/stop.gif    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/138/1/.cp/org/eclipse/jface/action/images/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/138/1/.cp/org/eclipse/jface/action/   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/138/1/.cp/org/eclipse/jface/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/138/1/.cp/org/eclipse/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/138/1/.cp/org/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/138/1/.cp/icons/full/title_banner.png Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/138/1/.cp/icons/full/message_info.gif Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/138/1/.cp/icons/full/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/138/1/.cp/icons/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/138/1/.cp/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/138/1/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/138/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/160/1/.cp/icons/full/eview16/resource_persp.gif   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/160/1/.cp/icons/full/eview16/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/160/1/.cp/icons/full/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/160/1/.cp/icons/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/160/1/.cp/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/160/1/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/160/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/4/1/.cp/icons/pixel-perfect.png   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/4/1/.cp/icons/hierarchyviewer-16.png  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/4/1/.cp/icons/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/4/1/.cp/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/4/1/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/4/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/157/1/.cp/icons/full/obj16/external_tools.gif Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/157/1/.cp/icons/full/obj16/   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/157/1/.cp/icons/full/wizban/ext_tools_wiz.png Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/157/1/.cp/icons/full/wizban/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/157/1/.cp/icons/full/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/157/1/.cp/icons/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/157/1/.cp/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/157/1/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/157/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/85/data/SCR   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/85/data/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/85/   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/6/1/.cp/libs/traceview.jar    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/6/1/.cp/libs/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/6/1/.cp/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/6/1/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/6/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/156/1/.cp/icons/full/dtool16/last_edit_pos.gif    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/156/1/.cp/icons/full/dtool16/next_nav.gif Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/156/1/.cp/icons/full/dtool16/prev_nav.gif Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/156/1/.cp/icons/full/dtool16/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/156/1/.cp/icons/full/etool16/last_edit_pos.gif    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/156/1/.cp/icons/full/etool16/next_nav.gif Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/156/1/.cp/icons/full/etool16/prev_nav.gif Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/156/1/.cp/icons/full/etool16/new_untitled_text_file.gif   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/156/1/.cp/icons/full/etool16/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/156/1/.cp/icons/full/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/156/1/.cp/icons/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/156/1/.cp/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/156/1/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/156/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/3/1/.cp/libs/liblzf-1.0.jar   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/3/1/.cp/libs/host-libprotobuf-java-2.3.0-lite.jar Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/3/1/.cp/libs/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/3/1/.cp/icons/connect.png Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/3/1/.cp/icons/opengl.png  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/3/1/.cp/icons/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/3/1/.cp/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/3/1/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/3/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/153/1/.cp/icons/full/eview16/defaultview_misc.gif Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/153/1/.cp/icons/full/eview16/new_persp.gif    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/153/1/.cp/icons/full/eview16/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/153/1/.cp/icons/full/progress/progress_error.gif  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/153/1/.cp/icons/full/progress/progress_ok.gif Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/153/1/.cp/icons/full/progress/progress_none.gif   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/153/1/.cp/icons/full/progress/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/153/1/.cp/icons/full/obj16/warn_tsk.gif   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/153/1/.cp/icons/full/obj16/generic_element.gif    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/153/1/.cp/icons/full/obj16/fldr_obj.gif   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/153/1/.cp/icons/full/obj16/file_obj.gif   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/153/1/.cp/icons/full/obj16/elements_obj.gif   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/153/1/.cp/icons/full/obj16/   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/153/1/.cp/icons/full/elcl16/trash.gif Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/153/1/.cp/icons/full/elcl16/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/153/1/.cp/icons/full/etool16/copy_edit.gif    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/153/1/.cp/icons/full/etool16/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/153/1/.cp/icons/full/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/153/1/.cp/icons/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/153/1/.cp/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/153/1/    Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/153/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.bundledata.1 Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.state.1  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.manager/.fileTable.5 Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.manager/.fileTableLock   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.manager/.fileTable.4 Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.manager/ Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.lazy.1   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher/com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor_25.2.2.3859397/splash.bmp Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher/com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor_25.2.2.3859397/   Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher/  Validate    Unexpected file DELETE
lib/monitor-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.update/platform.xml    Update  Modified    NONE
```

Comment: Try removing folder and then patch it again.

Comment: couldn't find the folder of 26.0.1 but got it solved by uninstalling previous update and then again downloading everything together. Thank you @DearDhruv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced the same issue

I took a backup of all the tools and sdk

And then reinstalled it which surprisingly solved my issue

Comment: Indeed thats the best thing someone can do to solve any issue in any kind of software..!!

Answer (score 1):

Just press the Cancel button and it should continue with its installation. Mine works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Android SDK Build-tool with SDK Manager. And then install again. For me, it works well

Answer (score 0):

I cancelled the errors and I just went ahead with the installation, it continued to run through and has worked fine for me.

You should receive multiple pop-ups, regarding the errors, if you cancel through them (press the x in the top corner) the installation will continue. and all should work

Comment: try to explain more